# Bootstrap Visual Studio

Tags: bootstrap, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Como quitar el Bootstrap de visual Studio 2017, me gustaría hacer una página pero no usando bootstrap sino con una librería de CSS propia

Comment: no puedes eliminarlo del head??? o quieres eliminarl de forma nativa... creo que seria en la seccion de extenciones: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293640(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si creastes un proyecto Asp.Net Core vas al "Solution Explorer" y das clic derecho en el nombre de tu proyecto, seleccionas Manage Bower Packages y en instalados selecciona Bootstrap y das Uninstall. De esta forma no queda rastro de bootstrap en tu proyecto.